HTTP 403 on model download from download.tensorflow.org
I'm following this repo BSTLD-Demo to reproduce the results of a research paper, but I'm getting HTTP 403: Forbidden error at RUN wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz && \ tar zxvf ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz in the Dockerfile of the project. I am also unable to find a viable alternative for the same.
I am getting the error when trying to build the Dockerfile. Here is the error
RUN wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz && \
41

 tar zxvf ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz
--2024-06-15 20:23:55--  http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz
Resolving download.tensorflow.org (download.tensorflow.org)...142.250.71.123, 142.250.70.123, 142.250.70.91, ...
Connecting to download.tensorflow.org (download.tensorflow.org)|142.250.71.123|:80...connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...403 Forbidden
2024-06-15 20:23:55 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Here are the contents of the Dockerfile.
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.4.1-cudnn-devel-ubuntu20.04
LABEL maintainer=eshalnov@graphics.cs.msu.ru

ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/%TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

WORKDIR /root

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y python3-pip \
  python3-dev \
  git \
  protobuf-compiler \
  wget \
  python3-opencv

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
  pip3 install six && \
  pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
  rm requirements.txt

RUN git clone http://github.com/tensorflow/models && \
  cd models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && \
  echo PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:`pwd`/slim:$PYTHONPATH

ENV MODELDIR=/root/models/research
ENV PYTHONPATH "$MODELDIR:$MODELDIR/slim:$PYTHONPATH"
ENV PATH "/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

RUN git clone https://github.com/e-sha/bstld && \
  cd bstld && \
  git checkout v1.0.2 && \
  cd ..

COPY ssd_mobilenet_v1.config .
RUN wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz && \
  tar zxvf ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_12_17.tar.gz

COPY models models/

COPY demo.ipynb .

ENTRYPOINT jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --ipc=host --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''

